# AWK: append text to specific line with 'system(external programm)' substitution

Tags: awk, command-substitution

I have a file called `data` that looks like this:

```
orange
apple
pair
mango
grape
```

by using
`awk -i inplace '{if (NR==4) $0=$0" is sweet"}{print}' data`, I get:

```
orange
apple
pair
mango is sweet
grape
```

I'm trying to achieve the same result through `system()` but I can't figure out how.

```
echo is sweet | xclip
```

`xclip -o` outputs `is sweet`. I'm trying

```
awk -i inplace '{if (NR==4) $0=$0(system("xclip -o"))}{print}' data
```

and `cat -n data` gives me

```
     1  orange
     2  apple
     3  pair
     4  is sweet
     5  mango0
     6  grape
```

Mango and grape have been pushed down one line, `is sweet` is on its own on line 4 and `mango` has a `0` in the end.

How can I change the command, and still use `system("xclip -o")` so that line 4 says `mango is sweet`, no appended `0` anywhere and no extra line, i.e. as with the first example?

I've super new with awk, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system("foo")` just calls a program `foo` and returns `foo`s **exit status** (i.e. 0 for success, non-zero for failure). You want something that will capture the **output** of `foo` (i.e. the text that `foo` writes to stdout), not it's **exit status**, so calling `system()` is the wrong approach. What you're seeing in your question is the output of `xclip -o` mixed in with the output of your awk script.

This is how to do what you want (using `date` instead of `xclip` since it's a command everyone has available):

```
$ awk '
    NR==4 {
        cmd = "date +%F"
        $0 = $0 " " ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "N/A" )
        close(cmd)
    }
    { print }
 ' file
orange
apple
pair
mango 2021-09-06
grape
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe for more information on the above and make sure to read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline to understand why I'm testing `getline`'s exit status before using it's output and why it's not something to be used in many situations (but this one is appropriate).

As a "one-liner" the above would be:

```
awk 'NR==4 { cmd = "date +%F"; $0 = $0 " " ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "N/A" ); close(cmd) } { print }' file
```

In case it's useful, here's a function that would do the equivalent for awk as command substitution for shell:

```
$ cat cmdsub.awk
function cmdsub(cmd,    line, n, out, cmd_stat, gl_stat) {
    ERRNO = ""
    while ( ( gl_stat=(cmd | getline line) ) > 0 ) {
        out = (n++ ? out ORS : "") line
    }
    cmd_stat = close(cmd)

    # If the above pipeline loop succeeded then all 3 error/status
    # variables will be 0 but if the above pipeline loop failed then
    #
    #    a) if cmd failed then
    #           i) ERRNO will be null
    #          ii) gl_stat will be 0 if 1st iteration, 1 otherwise.
    #         iii) cmd_stat will be non-zero if GNU awk,
    #                   poorly defined for POSIX awk so YMMV.
    #
    #    b) if cmd succeeded and getline failed then
    #           i) ERRNO will be non-null if GNU awk, null otherwise.
    #          ii) gl_stat will be less than zero
    #         iii) cmd_stat will be 0

    if ( (ERRNO == "") && ( (gl_stat != 0) || (cmd_stat != 0) ) ) {
        ERRNO = sprintf("CMD_STAT: %d, GL_STAT: %d", cmd_stat, gl_stat)
    }

    return out
}
BEGIN {
    print "foo", cmdsub("date +%F"), "bar"
    print (ERRNO ? "Failure: " ERRNO : "Success")
    exit (ERRNO ? 1 : 0)
}
```

```
$ awk -f cmdsub.awk
foo 2021-09-06 bar
Success

$ echo $?
0
```

It uses a global variable named `ERRNO`, the same as gawk already uses for getline failures (note: despite it's name, `ERRNO` is a string, not a number), and relies on `close(cmd)` returning a failure exit status when `cmd` fails which is what happens in gawk but in other awks YMMV as the POSIX standard is vague on that point.

For more info on `ERRNO` and `close()` see:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline
- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Close-Files-And-Pipes
- https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html

Comment: I am trying your suggested command on my Ubuntu latest lts, Ed, and throws an error: `awk: cmd. line:1: NR==4 {cmd="date +%F" $0=$0 " " ((cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "N/A") close(cmd)}{print}
awk: cmd. line:1:                         ^ syntax error`

Comment: There's nothing in the script I posted that would cause a syntax error in any awk so either you copy/pasted wrong or you're calling it from within a larger shell script and THAT has a problem. If it's the latter try copy/pasting it into http://shellcheck.net to see if it can help. Otherwise copy/paste exactly the command you're executing into your question (not a comment where it can't be formatted properly) so we can see what that command is.

Comment: You're right Ed, instead of copying/pasting, I wrote the command in one line and probably got some spaces wrong, as I often do! Thanks a lot for your solution. It works just fine!!

Comment: Actually what I cannot understand Ed, is trying to write your command in one line it throws an error specifically if between `"date +%F"` and `$0 = $0` there is no change of line.

Comment: Basically, lines that don't end in `{` or `}` can either end in newlines or `;`s so if you're going to squeeze a multi-line script onto 1 line you need to add `;` at the end of those lines that don't have a `{` or `}` at the end to replace the newline rather than just deleting it. I updated my answer to show the one-line version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to clarify every little detail. I really appreciate it!